# document management with time limiting options

Tags: security, collaboration, document-management

I have been asked to find a document management product that will allow us to set a view/download limit on a per file or group of files basis (e.g. user A is only allowed to view/download X documents in 24hrs)

is there any product which does this sort of thing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it has insufficient information. Forget everything you know about your product and read this question from a 'blank' standpoint. Do *you* understand what is required based on your text? And read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: @JanDoggen - this is hopefully a little clearer now

Comment: Hardly. Do you want a standalone product, or do you have to hook into an existing website (if so, what's it build with)? What OS? What price? What kinds of documents(files) does it have to serve? How do you want to handle user identification - a login (maybe an already existsing one), or IP based?

Comment: @JanDoggen - I just want to know if there is *anything* out there that can do this. I don't have any restriction on price or OS or preference for authentication at this stage which is why I didn't mention them. We don't have any existing system, so it would have to be standalone.

Comment: Not aware of one that does that directly.  You could change their document authority after 24 hours.